# SSL on an elastic beanstalk instance using docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am desperately trying to add SSL to our webapp which is running on elastic beanstalk with a single docker conatiner.
I followed the documentation of aws https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-docker.html and added all the needed information. After running eb deploy nothing changes in the config of the instance. SSHing onto it shows that none of the 2 needed files have been created.

envar.config:

```
    # 01_envar.config
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    PORT: 3000
    NODE_ENV: production

files:
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/https.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      # HTTPS Server

      server {
        listen 443;
        server_name localhost;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key;

        ssl_session_timeout 5m;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        location / {
          proxy_pass http://docker;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;

          proxy_set_header Connection "";
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        }
      }

  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
          -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

          -----END CERTIFICATE-----
          -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

          -----END CERTIFICATE-----
          -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

          -----END CERTIFICATE-----
          -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

          -----END CERTIFICATE-----      
  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
              -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
              -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Resources:
  sslSecurityGroupIngress: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      GroupId: {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["AWSEBSecurityGroup", "GroupId"]}
      IpProtocol: tcp
      ToPort: 443
      FromPort: 443
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

I'm very new to deploying apps on aws and any help would be really appreciated!

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can I reommend a different approach? If you're deploying elastic beanstalk with ELB, it can be much easier to configure SSL that way. Is that an option for you?

Comment: i was following the aws tutorial which said it is not possible for docker enviroments to use the load balancer, turns out that was false. I simply configured the load balancer to listen to port 443 and now its working.

Comment: Great to hear, I'm gonna write it down as an answer and would appreciate it if you could accept it for the next person to run into this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Configuring TLS into the ELB elastic beanstalk provides the environment takes less effort then configuring the environment nginx configuration, so it should be a better choice for most use-cases.